# when move a git project to other folder then move back, git status show all new

Tags: git, github

I have a `git project` at

```
~/workspace/A/project
```

And for some reasons I have to move the folder `project` to other folder, for example

```
~/usr/local/backup/project
```

Now, I move `project` back from `~/usr/local/backup` to `~/workspace/A`

And I cd to `~/workspace/A/project`

```
git status
```

git tell me that all the files are modified.
I don't want to submit all the files, what should i do ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: check permission of folder files

Comment: @Arv the permission is right

Comment: if you are using github as mention, you can clone your repo in that folder

Comment: What does `git diff` (or `git diff --cached` if you have any added changes) return? Does it think all the files are new, or just moved?

Comment: Tried it on OSX using the shell and mv and wasn't able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Did you include the .git directory when moved the files, probably but just in case?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of modified times. Is your other directory in a different filesystem mounted with 'noatime' or any other funky options?

Comment: Doesn't git only compare content, in contrast to SVN which compare modification time?